# ruby, postgres ,compare data from two tables coming from two databases

Tags: ruby, postgresql

we have a database legacy from a SQL SERVER, and now the new database is a postgres, I would like to do some testing to see if the content is the same from both tables, sinnce I still don't have acess to the legacy database (SQL server), I said let play with the new postgres database by polling two table and try to compare the data, in the iteration loop I got confused, any idea will be helpful :

```
require 'pg'
pg_conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "myDB", "userxx", "Zazzz")

all_children = pg_conn.exec("SELECT * from COMPANY;") 
all_children2 = pg_conn.exec("SELECT * from COMPANY2;")

all_children.each do |child|
??????
end
```

Thanks,

Comment: If that is your real username/password, please remove it.

Comment: Thanks Troy, I have removed it .

Comment: What needs to be compared?  everything? only some fields? is there a unique key that they both share?

Comment: we need to compare records are the same between the two tables.

Comment: @Fatna just so you know, there is edit history for questions and answers and everyone can see previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way would be to do a fast checking on one column, for example the name of the companies and compare the results to see the differences by substracting the resulting arrays :

```
require 'pg'
pg_conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "myDB", "userxx", "Zazzz")

all_children = pg_conn.exec("SELECT name from COMPANY;") 
all_children2 = pg_conn.exec("SELECT name from COMPANY2;")

# first check the count, if it's the same it's probably a good sign
puts all_children.length
puts all_children2.length

# check differences
results = all_children.uniq - all_children2.uniq
results2 = all_children2.uniq - all_children.uniq
```

For more complex tests you can maybe use the scientist gem from github : https://github.com/github/scientist

Edit:
sql version ?

```
 select * from company left outer join company2 on company.name = company.name2 where company2.name is null;
```

Comment: Thanks , this is a nice solution, is there any way to find what are the records that are different ? Thanks,

Comment: I'm not really sure, you could select the id + the name and check differences in ruby like in my example, but I don't think you have the same ids in the two tables. I just thought of another solution. Why doing that in ruby when you can use sql joins ? check my edit

Comment: Thanks jumichot, but if you read my question, the tables to be compared come from two different databases (postgres and sql server), so we can't use a sql join.

Comment: Ho to compare results to results2 ?

Comment: These are the results of substracting in the two ways to see all the differences between dataset : result wil give you the records that are only in the first database, and result2 the records that are only in the second database